# Conditional Go Routine/Channel

Tags: go, producer-consumer

I would like to make the statistics routine conditional so that it only runs on certain cases otherwise it will waste cycles half the time. Right now I have one go routine act as a producer to feed the two consumer routines via buffered channels. Is there a way I can make it so the statistics routine is conditional or is there a better pattern I should follow? Thanks in advance for any and all help!

```
func main() {
    options()
    go produce(readCSV(loc))
    go process()
    go statistics() // only on flag
    <-done
}

func produce(entries [][]string) {
    regex, err := regexp.Compile(reg)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error(reg + ", is not a valid regular expression")
    } else {
        for _, each := range entries {
            if regex.MatchString(each[col]) {
                matches <- each
                stats <- each // only on flag
            }
        }
    }
    done <- true
}

func process() {
    for {
        match := <-matches
        if len(match) != 0 {
            // PROCESS
        }
    }
}

func statistics() {
    for {
        stat := <-stats
        if len(stat) != 0 {
            // STATISTICS
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with making this conditional:

```
var stats chan []string  // Don't initialize stats.

func main() {
    options()
    go produce(readCSV(loc))
    go process()
    if flag {
        stats = make(chan []string, 1024)
        go statistics() // only on flag
    }
    <-done
}

func produce(entries [][]string) {
    regex, err := regexp.Compile(reg)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error(reg + ", is not a valid regular expression")
    } else {
        for _, each := range entries {
            if regex.MatchString(each[col]) {
                matches <- each
                if stats != nil {
                    stats <- each // only on flag
                }
            }
        }
    }
    close(done)
}

func process() {
    for {
        select {
        case match := <-matches:
            if len(match) != 0 {
              // PROCESS
            }
        case <-done:
            return
        }
    }
}

func statistics() {
    for {
        select {
        case stat := <-stats:
            if len(stat) != 0 {
                // STATISTICS
            }
        case <-done:
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is how I initially tackled it but when the flag is true I get a deadlock error for all go routines being asleep. Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to make sending to a channel conditional too. This answer shows the correct approach: `if stats != nil { ...`

Comment: I double checked, its the exact same as the example above

Comment: I can't give you a definite answer without a complete stacktrace, but my guess is that the deadlock is not because of statistics() but is because of how you handle done. I've updated my answer. Note the select clauses in `statistics` and `process`, and `close(done)` in `produce`. Please check it out and let me know if it fixes your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for the flag package.

```
import "flag"

var withStats = flag.Boolean("s", false, "Do statistics")

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    ...
    if *withStats == true {
        t := statType
        size := 100
        stats := make(chan, t, size)
        go statistics() // only on flag
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: This won't work, you will also need to make sending to `stats` channel conditional

Comment: I was mostly pointing at the flag package, but you are correct @kostya. Updated, thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, I am aware of the flag lib but decided to go my own route. My main issue is getting the conditional channel to run without causing deadlock.

Comment: Looks like the answer below is more suitable then.

Comment: @pdago have you considered using sync.WaitGroup?

Comment: Yes and no, it was one of the options I looked at but went with a simpler method. I will revisit that now, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

If you update statistics from many places in your code you might want to add some helper methods. Something like:

```
type stats struct {
    ch chan []string
}

func (s *stats) update(a []string) {
    if s != nil {
        s.ch <- a
    }
}

func (s *stats) start() {
    if s != nil {
        s.ch = make(chan []string)
        go statistics()
    }
}

var s *stats
if enabled {
    s = new(stats)
}
s.start()

// later in the code
s.update(each)
```

Comment: Although I don't this is still awesome and will come in handy later down the road. Thank you very much for the share!